# Gnome shell Alt+Tab

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

I am using Gnome-shell on arch linux. I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> frequently to switch between applications. Recently, I have assigned the language switcher to <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left shift</kbd>. This breaks <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch application backwards, while this doesn't happen in windows. Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a fix but a workaround... you have to go to *"Layout Options"*, open *"Miscellaneous compatibility options"* and check *"Shift cancels Caps Lock"*. Now your <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will work as expected but your language switcher will be triggered by <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> **not** by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd>. It's practically the same key combo only the key pressing order is different.

Comment: works. but what's the logic?